# Filtering arrays with partial exact match?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uisearchbar

I'm basically looking to exactly match how almost any search handles filtering.

Every guide for search filtering I've seen so far offers

```
let lower = searchBar.text!.lowercaseString

filteredInterestArray = interestsArray.filter({$0.title.rangeOfString(lower) != nil})
```

which basically gives something like:

["Cat", "Rat", "Bat", "Atlas"]

If you type in "at" every single one will show up, when really only Altas should show up. Also, if you typed in "stla", atlas would show up which is obviously very unintuitive.

How is proper filtering accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For achieving this, you can use the [hasPrefix(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1540100-hasprefix) method instead of `rangeOfString` method.

Use:

```
let lower = searchBar.text!.lowercaseString
filteredInterestArray = interestsArray.filter({$0.title.hasPrefix(lower)})
```

Answer (score 1):

`NSString` provides [hasPrefix:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/hasPrefix:) to determine if a string starts with another.

The OP doesn't indicate whether the strings in `interestsArray` are lowercase to begin with, but if they aren't, you'll have to [force them to lower](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSString/lowercaseString) before checking.